# How do I define multiple types of navigation containers in the same component?

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am new to the world of react native, so I need a hand with structuring my navigation pages. I want my app to have instagram like structure - that is the main page should be `createBottomTabNavigator` From there I have few different pages, and I can switch between them easily. Here is my code:

```
export default const MyTabs = ({ currentUser, navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Network"
        component={NetworkScreen}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Entypo name="map" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Then in my `App.js` file I call it like this:

```
return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <MyTabs />
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
    );
```

The above code works fine. The problem is when I want to perform more complicated navigation. For instance, in my home page I have list of objects and once, I click on these objects I want to navigate to a new page - with Stack navigator. How do I do so, and where should I define this page? Do I define it somehow inside my `Home` page, or inside my `App.js` page? In my mind it should be something like this:

```
<Stack.Screen
              name="Details"
              component={DetailScreen}
            />
```

I tried to put it inside `App.js`, something like this:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <NavigationContainer>
    <MyTabs />
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Meetup Details"
        component={MeetupDetails}
        options={{
          headerTitle: "Meetup Details",
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
</Provider>;
```

But ofc it didn't work.

Also I have another question - in my bottom tab I can navigate to `My profile` screen and that works fine. But I want to view other profiles as well. So my bottom tab is reserved for my own profile, but how do I define another `Profile` screen, which can go to other user's profile? Does it need to be with stack navigator? Does it again need to be defined in `App.js`?   Is it ok to define two different navigators (bottom tab and stack) with the same page (`Profile`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when you have a bottom tab navigator, each tab will be a `StackNavigator`

```js
export default const MyTabs = ({ currentUser, navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home" // here this would be BottomTabRoutes.HOME
        component={HomeNavigator}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Network"  // here this would be BottomTabRoutes.NETWORK
        component={NetworkNavigator}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Profile"  // here this would be BottomTabRoutes.PROFILE
        component={ProfileNavigator}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Entypo name="map" color={color} size={26} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

And then your `MeetupDetails` screen will be contained inside the `HomeNavigator` which is a `StackNavigator`

```js
export const HomeNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
       ...
      }}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name={HomeRoutes.HOME}
        component={Home}
        options={{
          headerStyle: styles.header,
          title: 'Home'
        }}
      />
       <Stack.Screen
        name={HomeRoutes.MEETUP_DETAILS}
        component={MeetupDetails}
        options={{
          headerStyle: styles.header,
          title: 'Meetup Details'
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
    
  }
```

Also, I would suggest to store your routes names in an enum, in this way it will be easier and their possible route props in a tpye
Something like this:

```js
export enum BottomTabRoutes {
  HOME = 'Home',
  NETWORK = 'Network',
  PROFILE = 'Profile',
}

export type BottomTabRouteProps = {
  [BottomTabRoutes.HOME]: {title: string}; // this is another parameter example
  [BottomTabRoutes.PROFILE]: undefined;
  [BottomTabRoutes.NETWORK]: undefined;
};
```

And the same for each Stack Navigator:

```js
export enum HomeRoutes = {
  HOME = 'Home',
  MEETUP_DETAILS = 'Meetup Details',
}


export type HomeRouteProps = {
  [HomeRoutes.HOME]: undefined
  [HomeRoutes.MEETUP_DETAILS: { someParamName: SomeType } // this might be a parameter you'll send through navigation
}

// Therefore, your MeetupDetails screen will look something like this: 

export const MeetupDetails = (props: StackScreenProps<HomeRouteProps, HomeRouteProps.MEETUP_DETAILS>,) => {
  
  const navigationParam = props.route.params.someParamName

  
  return (
    <View>
    ...
    
    </View>
    
    )
    
  }
```

**EDIT**

Regarding the Profile Screen, I believe you can have something like this:

```js
export const MainNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name={MainNavigatorRoutes.HOME} component={HomeNavigator} />
      <Stack.Screen name={MainNavigatorRoutes.USER} component={UserNavigator} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};


export const UserNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={({navigation}) => ({
       ...)}>
      <Stack.Screen
        name={UserNavigatorRoutes.SOME_OTHER_SCREEN}
        component={UserSettings}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name={UserNavigatorRoutes.USER_PROFILE}
        component={UserProfile}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};


export const HomeNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{title: ''}} >
     <Stack.Screen
          name={HomeNavigatorRoutes.HOME_TABS}
          component={HomeTabNavigator}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export const HomeTabNavigator = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator >
    <Stack.Screen
      name={HomeTabNavigatorRoutes.TAB_NAVIGATOR}
      component={MyTabs}
      options={{headerShown: false}}
    />
  </Stack.Navigator>
```

Basically, the structure will look like this: MainNavigator = { HomeNavigator, UserNavigator }. In this way, each navigator will be separate and you should be able to navigate to any screen from UserNavigator even if you are in a screen from UserNavigator

Comment: An enum provides no advantage when you're annotating the navigator and props, just extra typing and additional imports.

Comment: I believe it provides advantages in terms of typescript best practices and if there are many parameters sent through navigation for example, it helps to avoid typo bugs and unhandled undefined cases that are not so obvious when you do not use types. Also, if you're having absolute imports across the app, the imports won't be messy. But this is just my opinion (:

Comment: Thank you, this does clarify some things for me. I already accepted your answer, however, could you please advice on my question about "Profile screen"? Should I define it in every screen when I need it? For instance, I will have comments, chats, likes, and when listed, I wiould like to navigate to respected usrs profile. Do I need to define it in every place where I need to navigate to "Profile Screen"?

Comment: It does, thank you!

Comment: > it helps to avoid typo bugs and unhandled undefined cases that are not so obvious when you do not use types - that's why I said that it has no advantage when you have types. if you have types, then you already get all that without enums without extra import and longer characters to type. enums are also not typescript best practices, typescript best practices are about staying close to JS, which enums are not